# How to publish a new app compatible for Android 10/11 today?

Tags: android, store, playback

I read this documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

It specifies the minimal requirement to publish a new app is a Android 12 today.... But it's ugly, is there a possibility to publish a new app today that is compatible with Android 10/11 in the Play Store?

Because not all Android phones that people have today are compatible with Android 12, It's too new!

Comment: No, you misunderstand. You must TARGET Android 12. This controls certain behaviour and appearance. MINIMUM SDK controls which devices the app can actually run on. Your app can still run on very old devices as long as you set `minSdk` lower.

Comment: Thank, but what means "targetting Android 12" ?

Comment: having `targetSdk = 31` in your `build.gradle`. this makes your app able to use features (and handle restrictions...) introduced in Android 12. still you can have `if` in your code and use "new feature" only when app runs on never device. app will be "installable" on devices with at least `minSdk` (also `build.gradle`)